# How to get IRK on peripheral if central uses BR/EDR pairing

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I am programming a device which uses BR/EDR and BLE. BR/EDR is mostly used for audio data while BLE should work as control channel. Access to the used BLE characteristic returns a gatt_status_insufficient_authentication if and only if the central (smart phone) is not bonded. At least, that is what I want.

Moreover, if BLE bonding is triggered, I also get a BR/EDR bonding by Cross Transport Key Derivation (CTKD). Ok.

IF I do BR/EDR pairing from the phones pairing menu, this CTKD does not work. How could this work?

Or is there a way to enforce BLE pairing instead BR/EDR pairing?

Regards

Comment: Just a small comment: if the device is not bonded you should return insufficient authentication instead of insufficient authorization, per GAP requirements.

Comment: Thank you. I always get confused with that. Is somewhere defined what that means in the context of pairing/bonding?

Comment: Sure. See Bluetooth Core Specification v5 Vol 3 Part C section 10.3.1. Table 10.2 shows all different cases what you should respond. Section 10.5 in the same chapter defines "authorization". Basically it's just means the user must in some implementation-defined way confirm the action.